# Google search shows outdated results for a high-frequency changing paginated website

Tags: seo, google-search, pagination, change-frequency

I have a paginated website that publishes links to news articles from different news sources in a specific niche every hour in a most-recent-first fashion. The website is paginated so `www.example.com?p=1` is the first page, `www.example.com?p=2` is the second page and so on.

The problem is: `www.example.com?p=1` will possibly have a completely different content after an hour. It will definitely have a completely different content after a day. That said, every time I see an article of the website appearing on Google Search, the result does not match the search query. What's the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: See also: [SEO pagination for items sorted in reverse chronological order](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/58715/17633) -- and on [ux.se]: [Paging and Bookmarking](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/59640/17023)

Answer (score 2):

Frequency of the refresh will depend on your website popularity and credibility according to google rules. (that must be the start of your reflexion)

If you're in a specific niche, you may be be split your news in categories, so request will display result less far from the search query.

So, you may should increase:
Popularity of your website (linking campaign) to increase google refresh rate
Split your content in différent category

Is the content high quality, fresh AND not duplicate ? if not improving it can help